# Chrome DevTools Keeps Closing (Crashing?) On Mac (Ventura 13.5.1)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I open up DevTools (either from the keyboard shortcut or from the menu), it opens up for a second and then closes. It might be crashing, but I'm not sure.

I've tried incognito mode. I've tried clearing browsing data. I have all my extensions turned off. I have tried to boot in safe mode. I have even tried reinstalling Chrome. None of that fixes it.

I'm using Chrome v116.0.5845.140

Edit: Works in Chrome Beta